# Where can I find a canonical list of the latest firmware for Canon cameras?

Tags: canon, firmware

Are there a list somewhere stating the latest firmware version for the different Canon EOS cameras. Having a lot of different bodies it would help a lot not having to check out each product's page one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all except the Rebel series there is this list that goes back as far as the original 5D and 40D.

https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/professional-model-firmware-updates

I'm not aware of any such list that includes the Rebel series from Canon.

Comment: Without the Rebels is fine, since I don't use anything with more than to digits. The bodies I have dates back to the first 1ds though. It would be nice to have a complete list. But thanks anyway, the one you linked to helps a lot.

Comment: I highly doubt you'll see any more firmware updates for the 1Ds. The latest revision was released in July, 2002. It would surprise me quite a bit if any body older than the 5D which last received an update over 5 years ago does.

Comment: @Hugo Note that the list covers recent _updates_, not just recent _models_, so even if the 1Ds were to be updated, it should appear there.

Comment: @MichaelClark I doubt that too. I was just pointing out that due to the fact that I have a lot of bodies (thus a complete list would be great) and that some of those where not on the list. That the 1Ds wont get any more firmware updates is not a surprise, still it would be a great resource to have a complete list of the most recent firmware released for all bodies just to make sure that they actually use the most recent software albeit old such. As Imre pointed out the list provided just shows the recent ones and that is almost as good.